# Importing/Exporting Modules - Node JS/Discord JS

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I feel as if i'm exporting/importing Currency into Balance.js incorrectly.

I've found one article :- [Discord.js currency to command handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60537931/discord-js-currency-to-command-handler)

Which in my eyes, i've followed correctly, but i still get the getBalance undefined error.

I've been looking at this for the last four days trying various ways  but im getting no where.

I believe this is due to how i'm exporting/importing the currency collection

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

**App.JS**

```
        const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Prefix, Token } = require('./config.json');
const { Characters, CurrencyShop } = require('./dbObjects');
const { Op  } = require('sequelize');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const currency = new Discord.Collection();

Reflect.defineProperty(currency, 'add', {
    value: async function add(id, amount) {
        const user = currency.get(id);
        if (user) {
            user.balance += Number(amount);
            return user.save();
        }
        const newUser = await Characters.create({ character_id: id, balance: amount });
        currency.set(id, newUser);
        return newUser;
    },
});

Reflect.defineProperty(currency, 'getBalance', {
    value: function getBalance(id) {
        const user = currency.get(id);
        return user ? user.balance : 0;
    },

});

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    };

client.once('ready', async () => {
const storedBalances = await Characters.findAll();
storedBalances.forEach(b => currency.set(b.user_id, b));
console.log(` Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', async message => {
if (message.author.bot) return; 
    currency.add(message.author.id, 1);
return currency;
if (!message.content.startsWith(Prefix)|| message.author.bot) return;

const args = message.content.slice(Prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

const command = client.commands.get(commandName);
if (!command) return;
try {
    await command.execute(message, args);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
}
});
module.exports = { currency }
client.login(`${Token}`);
process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
console.error('Unhandled promise rejection:', error);
})
```

**Balance.JS**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Characters, CurrencyShop } = require('../dbObjects');
const { currency } = require('../app.js');

module.exports = {
name: "balance",
args: false,
async execute (message) {
        const target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        return message.channel.send(`${target.tag} has ${currency.getBalance(target.id)}`);
},
};
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBalance' of undefined
at Object.execute (C:\Users\Unknown\Bot\commands\balance.js:9:62)
at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Unknown\Bot\app.js:54:17)
at Client.emit (events.js:310:20)
at MessageCreateAction.handle 
(C:\Users\Unknown\node_modules\discord.js\src\
client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)at Object.module.exports [as 
MESSAGE_CREATE] 
(C:\Users\Unknown\node_modules\discord.js\src\
client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket 
(C:\Users\Unknown\node_modules\discord.js\src\
client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket 
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Unknown\node_modules\discord.js\src\
client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Unknown\node_modules\ws\lib\event- 
target.js:125:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage 
(C:\Users\Unknown\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:800:20)
at Receiver.emit (events.js:310:20)
at Receiver.dataMessage 
(C:\Users\Unknown\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:436:14)
at Receiver.getData 
(C:\Users\Unknown\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:366:17)
at Receiver.startLoop 
(C:\Users\Unknown\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:142:22)
at Receiver._write 
(C:\Users\Unknown\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:77:10)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
at Receiver.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
at TLSSocket.socketOnData 
(C:\Users\Unknown\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:875:35)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:12)
```

Comment: Please include log files or at least, the full error (with line numbers)

Comment: Added! Sorry - New to this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after spending a while reproducing your environment... 
The problem I found was that you are "requiring" the commands/modules before declaring the module.exports in `app.js`. This means that `balance.js` gets an empty map instead of `{currency: currency}` when it is "required".

In the example below, this acts the same way as your "broken" code. To fix it, you need to move the `require("./test2")` into `start()` because `start()` is executed after the `module.exports`.

**test.js**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const currency = new Discord.Collection();

const test2 = require("./test2");

function start() {
    test2.test();
}

module.exports = { currency: currency };
start();
```

**test2.js**

```
const { currency } = require("./test");

module.exports = { 
    test: () => {
        console.log(require("./test"));
        console.log(currency);
    }
}
```

**The fix**

To translate this into your environment:  you should move all your code (except for require, constants and module exports) into something like this:

```
const a = ....
const b = ....
const client = ...
// etc....

client.on("ready" () => {
  // Put (almost) everything here
  // code here will run after module.exports because client.login is executed after
});

module.exports = { currency }
client.login(`${Token}`);
process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
console.error('Unhandled promise rejection:', error);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That makes complete sense - thank you ever so much.